# Optimal way to share one external drive to multiple machines

Tags: mac, file-sharing, external-hard-drive

I bought an external drive (WD "My Passport" 2Tb USB3.0) and am looking for the "right way" to share it between a PC and Mac. I am currently sharing a folder on the PC's HDD with my Mac over wifi (smb), and I could just hook the drive up to my PC and share it the same way I am sharing the C drive.

Is there a way to utilize USB3 to share the external drive with both machines?

Comment: Please do not cross post. If you want a post moved please Flag it and describe why. Thank you!

Comment: I thought that if you had a USB enabled wifi router that it would allow the sharing of an external hard drive like that? Also they make wifi enabled external hard drives as well that could be a good solution to your problem.

Comment: I didn't actually. Whew! Seems this question was already on SU and they've basically said the same thing as @mfinni before it was merged from ServeFault. I probably should have thought to look at SU, but it seemed to me like a networking question. Thank you for the advice about cross posting, I didn't understand these sites were connected like that.

Comment: I'll check into that

Comment: Some WiFi routers allow you to share USB storage over SMB or NFS. But it's essentially what he's doing now. It does NOT allow sharing as a USB device to multiple computers.

Comment: This is the one that was here already. It mentions a USB bridge cable? http://superuser.com/questions/227390/share-external-usb-hard-drive-over-usb-between-multiple-computers

Comment: I am to late with this since you already bought the drive, but it sounds is if you really wanted a NAS.

Comment: Would that still leave me connecting to wifi? I can take the drive back, it's unopened :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using one of the proper ways to do this - a network file system. NFS or SMB/CIFS are examples of this. The server that it's directly attached to mediates access to the files by the clients.

You can't directly attach a disk to multiple hosts and allow them to use it, without using a cluster-aware filesystem that is correctly configured on all the hosts. Examples are NTFS with Windows Clustering, or VMFS for VMware ESX(i). If there isn't a way for the attached hosts to coordinate with each other that they're writing to the same disk, they will trash it badly.