# External Hard Drive To Android Tablet and Power Supply

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, power-supply

Is it possible via USB Y cable or any other means to connect a Samsung 10.1 30 pin to 
an external hard drive and at the same time, an external power supply to the Hard Drive.
I have concluded getting an adapter for the tablet to go from 30 pin to USB.
Any other takes on this..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share external USB hard drive over USB between multiple computers](http://superuser.com/questions/227390/share-external-usb-hard-drive-over-usb-between-multiple-computers)

Comment: Judging by your attempt to comment on the answer below it appears you have lost control of your account.  You should consider [registering](http://superuser.com/help/why-register) your account as it will allow you to post comments to answers on your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is very much possible, the hard drive can be powered seperately and connected to an android device by using a hub like the following : http://www.vantecusa.com/en/product/view_detail/586

You need an OTG cable for the device aswell, whivh you van get at any local store for a couple of dollars.

Comment: No go,I guess I should have been more specific.
The external hard drive is a portable USB powered.
The item mentioned for a fix is for SATA.